# How to measure the performance speed of one method in java

Tags: java, performance

I have implemented a protocol and it is executed and give me the output I want but the problem is the runtime execution. Is a little more than I would expected. I wanted to measure the execution time of one of my methods of the class but I am not sure if what I have done is correct since I do not have much experience in testing.
What I have done is:

```
public class MyClass {
    // some private fields here

    public int method toBeMeasured (int a){
        long startTime=System.nanoTime();

        // the code under my method including 
        // some for cycles and some operation.

        long finalTime=System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        return something of type int;
    }
}
```

Now what I need to know if the result I got is really telling me the performance speed of this method or am I measuring it wrong. Also I want to know how can I measure this 10000 times and take the average of those times. I hope to receive any feedback for my question.

Comment: The performance measurement you get from that code will not be reliable.  See the linked Q&A for an explanation, and hints on how to get reliable measurements.

Comment: @Stephen C , ok i know it is not reliable but i also doubt if i am at least measuring the runtime performance speed of my method or am i doing it wrong

Comment: You are wrong about that.  Please read the linked Q&A to understand why.

Comment: Can you send me the link please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java